# How we can save data on two servers using one sumit form?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using third party tool. Here is form for that:

```
<form method="POST"
action="https://www.thewiseagent.com:443/secure/webcontactAllFields.asp"
name="myForm" onSubmit="return chkForm(this);">
<!-- Do not change -->
    <input type="hidden" name="ID" value="67,176,210,31,93,194,29,70,235">
<!-- These fields can be edited -->
    <input type="hidden" name="responsePage" value="http://http://www.expertforyou.com/">
    <input type="hidden" name="Source" value="website referral">
    <input type="hidden" name="Categories" value=""><!-- semicolon;delimited no spaces -->
    <input type="hidden" name="currentUser" value=""><!-- internal team member -->
    <input type="hidden" name="ProgramID" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="noMail" value="0"><!-- 0/1 if set to 1, no reply to the visitor is sent. -->
    <input type="hidden" name="replyMessage" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="replySubject" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="notifySubject" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="notifyCc" value=""><!-- comma, delimited -->
    <input type="hidden" name="notifyBcc" value=""><!-- comma, delimited -->

<!-- These address fields are optional -->
    <input type="hidden" name="address" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="city" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="state" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="zip" value="">

<!-- For any additional fields, add the field names separated by a comma to the CommaDelimitedFormFields value. These fields will be saved in the extra notes section -->
    <input type="hidden" name="CommaDelimitedFormFields" value="">

<script language=javascript>
<!--
function chkForm(theForm) {
      if(theForm.CFirst.value=="") {
            alert("Please fill in your first name.");
            theForm.CFirst.focus();
            return false;
      }
      if(theForm.CLast.value=="") {
            alert("Please fill in your last name.");
            theForm.CLast.focus();
            return false;
      }
      var email = theForm.CEmail.value;
      if(email.indexOf("@")<1){
            alert("Please fill in your email address \n so I may contact you.");
            theForm.CEmail.focus();
            return false;
      }
      if(document.all) {
            if(theForm.Message.innerText=="") {
                  alert("Please type a message.");
                  theForm.Message.focus();
                  return false;
            }
      } else {
            if(theForm.Message.value=="") {
                  alert("Please type a message.");
                  theForm.Message.focus();
                  return false;
            }
      }
return true;
}
-->
</script>
    <tr>
        <td align="right"> First Name</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="CFirst" size="30" class="CFirst">
            <font size="1">*</font>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right"> Last Name</td>
        <td>
        <input type="text" name="CLast" size="30" class="CLast">
        <font size="1">*</font></td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right"> Phone</td>
        <td>
        <input type="text" name="Phone" size="30" class="Phone">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right"> Fax</td>
        <td align="left">
        <input type="text" name="Fax" size="30" class="Fax">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right"> Email</td>
        <td>
        <input type="text" name="CEmail" size="30" class="CEmail">
        <font size="1">*</font> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right" valign="top"> Message</td>
        <td valign="top">
        <textarea rows="8" name="Message" id="Message" cols="40"></textarea>
    <tr>
        <td> </td>
        <td align="left" valign="top">
        <?php    if ( function_exists('wp_nonce_field') )
        wp_nonce_field('submit_form', 'submit_form');
        ?>
        <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Send" id="submit">
        </td>
    </tr>
</form>
```

The form above saves data into external server, but now I need to save that into my server as well.
So i am using jQuery for this.
Here is the code for that:

```
$(function(){
    $('#submit').click(function() {
    var $nonce = $("input#submit_form").val();
    var $first = $("input.CFirst").val();
    var $last = $("input.CLast").val();
    var $Phone = $("input.Phone").val();
    var $Fax = $("input.Fax").val();
    var $CEmail = $("input.CEmail").val();
    var $message = $("textarea#Message").val(); 
    var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
    if($message != '' && $first !='' && $last!='' && $CEmail!='') {
        $.ajax({
            url:"../wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
            type:'POST',
            data:'action=contact_form&nonce='+$nonce+"&first="+$first+"&last="+$last+"&Phone="+$Phone+"&Fax="+$Fax+"&CEmail="+$CEmail+"&message="+$message,
            success: function() {
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Now if I remove action from the form tag it will insert entries into my databse but that i cant do as i have to save data into external server as well. 
Can any one know how we can do this?

Thanks

Comment: Please format your code properly using the "code" button in the editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the part that submits data to the server:

```
                    $.ajax({
                        url:"../wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
                        type:'POST',
                        data:'action=contact_form&nonce='+$nonce+"&first="+$first+"&last="+$last+"&Phone="+$Phone+"&Fax="+$Fax+"&CEmail="+$CEmail+"&message="+$message,
                           success: function() {

                                }
                           });
                    }
```

Just call it twice and set a different URL to the receiver of the post:

```
                    $.ajax({
                        url:"https://www.thewiseagent.com:443/secure/webcontactAllFields.asp",
                        type:'POST',
                        data:'action=contact_form&nonce='+$nonce+"&first="+$first+"&last="+$last+"&Phone="+$Phone+"&Fax="+$Fax+"&CEmail="+$CEmail+"&message="+$message,
                           success: function() {

                                }
                           });
                    }
```

Comment: Perhaps it's better to contain fields in two separate forms, and then submit the appropriate form.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, **do not `$`-prefix** JS vars unless they are jQuery objects. `.val()` returns plain strings (or arrays for some fields).

Then, to solve your problem, you need to submit the form to your server using AJAX first and then, when the request has finished (i.e. in the success callback), submit the form to the external server which you need to specify in the `action` of the form.

Comment: can you give me an example?? so that i can understand better